# Create non-GIS Front End to ESRI Server Web Map

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have a webmap that I have created using the ESRI ArcGIS Javascript API / Web App Builder. It [manages City projects](http://maps.cityoftulsa.org/IOT/). The departments that manage this data would like a web-interface to manage the information. They want to update in an excel spreadsheet (or something similar) and have the webmap autoupdate. Now I have two thoughts here.

1. Create a web-editor map giving edit-level capabilities to the feature classes involved and place this map on an INTERNAL-ONLY server so that only City employees can access this.
2. Create a web-form that displays and interacts with the database data only, no spatial access.

My problem is, I have experience building the web-map editor where users view a web-map, click on the targeted features, and pop-up the edit toolbar. But the desired option is to provide a spreadsheet entry point to allow a non-GIS clerical user to update the information without any GIS training. I'm wondering if anyone has information on how someone would create a non-map-based edit point for GIS data on an ArcGIS Enterprise Server?

Answer (score 3):

Options that we have used is to create a list in Microsoft SharePoint that is connected to the database that is being used by the web mapping system.  In our case that has been SDE running on MS SQL, but we have also done it connected directly to MS SQL Spatial, and avoiding Esri.
This gives the user a non-map based interface that looks like an spreadsheet.
You could also connect Excel directly to a SQL database using the 'from other source' button on the data tab.
These are some non-programmer ways of doing things, but there are quite a number of more elegant programmed options.
Bryan

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your eGIS and systems are set up you can run a Python job to consume the excel rows on intervals and publish/apply edits as feature or map service.  You can use Google also to work with Python if the sheets/rows are to be made public.

Answer (score 0):

here is a fresh new alternative, we are soon releasing cartoserver. this is a GIS web service that is compatible we ArcGIS server Feature Services. You can do a lot of operations online and without having an ArcGIS server or any GI Server installed. It is best used for this type of applications.
You can find a sample here http://cartologic.com/sandbox/cartoserver/#/geo-tables
use cartoview/cartoview to sign in.
Once you signed in you can upload a shapefile and the define this shapefile as a feature service. all from the browser. You users need to learn how to create a shapefile. If this is too difficult, then you can extend the code to upload excel files